Checkboxes rendered through map - make each unique
I have the following code which loops through product items (FoodWeight) and then loops through people (tr) - I have commented these below.
I want to select a person for each item mapping. The current problem is that I select a person on the first item and then this content shows on all other product items.
How do I get it, so that this content is unique for each item so for that product item it shows the people but nothing selected?
It has something to do with handleCheckboxChange - like it is keeping that indice for all items rather than just showing for that particular item.
  const [visibleDivIndices, setVisibleDivIndices] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (i) => {
    setVisibleDivIndices((prevIndices) =>
      prevIndices.includes(i)
        ? prevIndices.filter((i) => i !== i)
        : [...prevIndices, i]
    );
  };

{FoodWeight.map(el => {
/* THIS IS THE PRODUCT ITEM MAP */
if (el.id == checkbox.id) {
let number = el.Quantity;
return (
<div className="selection-wrapper">
<TextField value={number}  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, }}
id="standard-basic"
label="Qty"
name="quantity" onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()}
className="second-selection-qty"
onChange={e => {quantityfunctionFood(e.currentTarget.value, checkbox.id, checkbox)
}}
type="Number"
variant="outlined"
/>
{tr?.map((item, i) => {
/* THIS IS THE PERSON MAP */
return (
<>
<FormControlLabel key={(item.Name)+i} value={item.Name + '-' + index} control={<Checkbox onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(i)}></Checkbox>} label={item.Name}></FormControlLabel>
{visibleDivIndices.includes(i) && (
<>{getselecteddata.map(els => {
return (
<>This content should only be displayed after checking the checkbox for the person</>
)})}
</>)}
</>)})}
</div>
)
}
})}


Please provide a snippet of code with values for your variables, also I suppose you're using material-ui but you didn't mention anything about it here, therefore it's hard to understand what your code should do or at least to make it work


Changed visibleDivIndices from an array to an object that maps each product item's id to an array of selected indices.

Modified the handleCheckboxChange function to target a specific product item (el.id) and update the visibility state for that product item only.

Updated the visibility check to access the visibleDivIndices for each product item using el.id.




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField, FormControlLabel, Checkbox } from '@mui/material';

const ProductSelection = ({ FoodWeight, tr, getselecteddata, checkbox, quantityfunctionFood }) => {
  const [visibleDivIndices, setVisibleDivIndices] = useState({});

  // Function to handle checkbox selection
  const handleCheckboxChange = (elId, i) => {
    setVisibleDivIndices((prevIndices) => {
      const currentIndices = prevIndices[elId] || [];
      const updatedIndices = currentIndices.includes(i)
        ? currentIndices.filter(index => index !== i)
        : [...currentIndices, i];
      
      return {
        ...prevIndices,
        [elId]: updatedIndices
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {FoodWeight.map((el) => {
        /* THIS IS THE PRODUCT ITEM MAP */
        if (el.id === checkbox.id) {
          let number = el.Quantity;
          return (
            <div className="selection-wrapper" key={el.id}>
              <TextField
                value={number}
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                id="standard-basic"
                label="Qty"
                name="quantity"
                onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()}
                className="second-selection-qty"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  quantityfunctionFood(e.currentTarget.value, checkbox.id, checkbox);
                }}
                type="Number"
                variant="outlined"
              />
              
              {tr?.map((item, i) => {
                /* THIS IS THE PERSON MAP */
                return (
                  <div key={item.Name + i}>
                    <FormControlLabel
                      value={item.Name + '-' + el.id}
                      control={<Checkbox onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(el.id, i)} />}
                      label={item.Name}
                    />
                    {visibleDivIndices[el.id]?.includes(i) && (
                      <>
                        {getselecteddata.map((els) => {
                          return (
                            <>This content should only be displayed after checking the checkbox for the person</>
                          );
                        })}
                      </>
                    )}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductSelection;




Works well - thank you. Is there a way to clear the indices in a toggle? For example, clicking another checkbox removes this indice for this item?

Update handleChecboxChange
It removes current checkbox index (i) from list of selected indices
const handleCheckboxChange = (elId, i) => {
setVisibleDivIndices((prevIndices) => {
const currentIndices = prevIndices[elId] || [];
// If the checkbox is already selected, unselect it
const updatedIndices = currentIndices.includes(i)
  ? currentIndices.filter(index => index !== i) // Unselect the current checkbox
  : [i]; // Otherwise, select only this checkbox (clear others)

return {
  ...prevIndices,
  [elId]: updatedIndices,
};

});
};
